# Help with installation of ROOT, PATH variable is getting deleted

Tags: ubuntu, root, path

I am trying to install [ROOT](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/) which I need for work. I run Ubuntu 10.04 64 bit on virtualbox on my laptop. After extracting the tarball, I try to source the .sh file using the command as suggested in the README

$  . pathname/root/bin/thisroot.sh

It shows me the following error:

```
$ . /home/username/Downloads/root/bin/thisroot.sh

bash:/home/username/Downloads/root/bin/drop_from_path: No such file or directory
bash:/home/username/Downloads/root/bin/drop_from_path: No such file or directory
bash:/home/username/Downloads/root/bin/drop_from_path: No such file or directory
bash:/home/username/Downloads/root/bin/drop_from_path: No such file or directory
bash:/home/username/Downloads/root/bin/drop_from_path: No such file or directory
bash:/home/username/Downloads/root/bin/drop_from_path: No such file or directory
bash: man: No such file or directory
Command 'dirname' is available in '/usr/bin/dirname'
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin' is not included in
the PATH environment variable.
dirname: command not found
/usr/bin/env: bash: No such file or directory
Command 'grep' is available in '/bin/grep'
The command could not be located because '/bin' is not included in the
PATH environment variable.
grep: command not found
Command 'grep' is available in '/bin/grep'
The command could not be located because '/bin' is not included in the
PATH environment variable.
grep: command not found
```

The result of this is that it somehow deleted the PATH, because now I cannot do anything else from the command line. For example:

```
$ vi README
Command 'vi' is available in '/usr/bin/vi'
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin' is not included in
the PATH environment variable.
vi: command not found

$ clear
Command 'clear' is available in '/usr/bin/clear'
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin' is not included in
the PATH environment variable.
clear: command not found
```

I have an Ubuntu 11.04 on my desktop at home, where this installation went smoothly. I also tried this on my office mac, but I don't know what is happening here.

Comment: You should read the things in `thisroot.sh`, or paste it here (or use pastebin if it's too long).

Comment: Run `set -x; /path/to/thisroot.sh` to see a trace of what the script is doing.

Comment: I'm confused about what you are trying to install. The link you have up there (http://root.cern.ch/drupal/) goes to the ROOT system homepage. ROOT is a data analysis framework used by nuclear and particle physicists, while [Drupal](http://drupal.org/) is a content management system. (The ROOT guys uses drupal to maintain their website, which explains the presence of the string "drupal" in that URL).

Comment: @dmckee corrected. I succesfully installed this on my own later that day (from source, not using binaries. The real trouble was AliROOT on Ubuntu 11.04) so I did not get back here for a while. Incidentally, I was also building a wiki on drupal at the time so that was on my mind, and it just slipped out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start a script by sourcing it:

```
. script
```

or

```
source script
```

its commands are executed in the context of this shell. You don't have to worry about disappearing paths, aliases and such; if you later start another shell, that one will not be affected.